# KNN for regression

Tags: python

My codes worked fine just until few minutes ago, but when I re-ran them it gives me an error.
Could anyone help me why this is happening?

```py
    #1.3.1 split dataset into train and test data

    #split dataset into train and test data

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

    #Build a model (KNN for Regression)

    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
    reg_cv = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 3,  weights = 'distance', p=1)
    reg_cv.fit(X, y)
    score = cross_val_score(reg_cv, X, y, cv = 5)
    result = np.mean(score)
    print(result)

    #Cross Validation

    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    import numpy as np
    from statistics import mean 
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=5)
    print("CV, KFold:\n{}".format(cross_val_score(KNeighborsRegressor(), X, y, cv=kfold)))
```

Comment: The code in the image and your included code are very different.

Comment: don't post images of errors, either - we can't copy and paste that to a search engine, and that makes it harder for us to help you. Instead, please copy and paste the error as text into your question. But, as Michael says, you're asking us to look at something that's different from what goes wrong, so there's nothing to help you with...

Comment: sorry! i copy-pasted the code again. regarding error message, this website asks me to write the error message in code format, but it does not cover the error message into a code format. so i captured it as a picture. I also added the error message